# My Character Will Not Appear On PVZ Battle For Neighborville

Tags: pvz-battle-for-neighborville

I am writing this on my mobile device so I cannot show any screenshots.
Anyway, I'm playing on Windows 10 PC, and I have recently purchased the game. Every time I load the game or launch it, I can only play as 1 character. I can’t see any other character except the one I am playing.
When I change characters, it won’t load. My ability icons won’t load, and my character is invisible. I can’t move - only jump, and the crosshairs are covered by a red X.

I don’t know if this is a common problem, but, I did “repair” the game on origin by pressing the Repair feature.
That didn’t help at all.

Comment: Hey TumbleElf, welcome on Arqade SE. Take [the tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already and read [the help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need. If the repair didn't help, have you tried to uninstall re-install your game?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, repair and reinstall did not help.